# Doctrine 2: Pagination Link Generation

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, pagination, doctrine

I haven't found anything on this subject in particular and the Doctrine documentation is pretty spotty on pagination so here it goes:

I'm using Doctrine 2 on top of Laravel 4. I am trying to get pagination working and have gotten so far as returning the first page of results like so:

```
public function paginate($query, $page_size, $current_page){
    $paginator  = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator($query);

    $total_results = count($paginator);
    $pagesCount = ceil($total_results / $page_size);

    // now get one page's items:
    $paginator
        ->getQuery()
        ->setFirstResult($page_size * ($current_page-1)) // set the offset
        ->setMaxResults($page_size); // set the limit

    foreach ($paginator as $pageItem) {
        $results[] = $pageItem;
    }   

    return $results;
}
```

But this is only good for the first page. When I want to click over to page 'n' of results I have no clue how to go about starting that. I haven't found any way to store the DQL query (it can't be passed to the view or stored in a session variable).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have this method in my app using doctrine and laravel. Take a look:

```
public function paginate($pageNumber = 1, $recordsPerPage = 20)
{
    // updating page number according to records per page
    $pageNumber = ($pageNumber == 1)? 0 : (($pageNumber -1) * 20);

    /** @var $qb QueryBuilder $qb */
    $qb = \Doctrine::createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('m');
    $qb->from('models\MyModel', 'm');
    $qb->orderBy('m.name', 'asc');
    $qb->setMaxResults($recordsPerPage);
    $qb->setFirstResult($pageNumber);
    $records = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

    // creating the paginator with the results
    $paginator = \Paginator::make($records, $this->totalOfRecords(), $recordsPerPage);
    $paginator->setBaseUrl('my-paginator-url');

    // HERE you can do some stuff with the $paginator and $records vars
}


public function totalOfRecords()
{
    /** @var $qb QueryBuilder $qb */
    $qb = \Doctrine::createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('count(m)');
    $qb->from('models\MyModel', 'm');

    // return total of records 
    return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

Then, you can do something like this:

```
// paginate the first page with 10 records per page (showing records from 0 to 9)
$this->paginate(1, 10);

// paginate the third page with 20 records per page (showing records from 30 to 49)
$this->paginate(3, 20);
```